# WPF Usercontrol in a shared library

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls, shared-libraries

I have a class library project that acts as a shared library for common WPF methods. This consists of common converters, command handling, validations etc.

Now I want it to also include WPF usercontrols. This involves the possibility to design the usercontrol in the XAML designer. This is of course not possible in a project of type class library.

I've found a solution where I can start out creating a WPF project, create the usercontrol and then change the projectype to class library. However, since I allready got the class library this is too late.

So the question is if it is possible to create a usercontrol in a class library project that allready excists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add a wpf UserControl to a class library, but you have to make sure that these references are added:

- System.Xaml
- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- WindowsBase

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also noticed I could add usercontrols from the add menu. Always thought this was refering to WinForms usercontrols, but noticed you actually could select what type of usercontrol. Now I got things up and going.